# Symbol parsing hell in Java

Tags: java, parsing

I am writing a Java server that takes data from another server. Unfortunately, part of the string it throws out is not able to be 'parsed' by the program. `System.out.print` prints it as a question mark `?`

This wretched question mark symbol cannot be parsed by my client's JSON parser either. Does anyone know how I can remove it?

Trying `str.replace` with the `?` symbol didn't work.

Comment: Can we see the code that prints the symbol? Are you using "Char(int)"?

Comment: Are the data you receive from the other server formatted in a different language? You might need to use the appropriate Charset.

Comment: Do you anything know about various encodings of symbols?

Comment: It's probably a problem with the encoding (or the value of the character is outside of the range of the encoding/charset).  The `?` is probably an attempt at displaying that there is in fact a character, but it cannot be interpreted.

Comment: The '?' symbol usually appears when you read utf-8 encoded string as latin-1 (which is default for java servlets).
How do you send data from another server and receive it in your app?

Comment: In case it is not clear, the `?` symbol is not actually a literal `?` symbol in the encoding you are using.  It is a *filler* symbol that is simply there to state *I am a character, but I cannot be displayed*, which is why when trying the replace the `?` character, it is not actually there.  You have no `?`.

Comment: Is the question mark inside a black diamond?  That would suggest it is a filler.

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. The question mark is just your display device trying to display a char it does not recognise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this worked for me:

```
stringName.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
```

This was from some answer in stackoverflow but I can't find it now.

Comment: Not very clean, but as long as you only need US-ASCII characters, it's about fine. Any non-english characters are deleted this way. The clean way is more like Dariusz' answer, but you have to somehow figure out the charset for that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like an encoding problem. Your application uses one encoding, while the server uses other.

Using the `Charset` class will be your answer. Use it when converting received data to String. Most probably you'll have to specify it in a `Reader` constructor, though I can't say without any code.

Here is the link to appropriate javadoc: [InputStreamReader(InputStream, Charset)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)